# C# how to use Regex.replace, to replace all the pattern matches with the target string

Tags: c#, regex

Yes, I want to search and replace all the occurrences of the pattern and replace them with a target string. I am trying to use Regex.Replace(src, pattern, target), is there a flag like \g to put in pattern to make it work, or what?

Comment: It may help to have a look at your regular expression and also a better description of what "isn't working."

Comment: No, it replaces all instances by default. Why don't we focus on the problem instead of what you think is the solution?

Comment: Why don't you post the code snippet you are having difficulty with? It's hard to comprehend what you are attempting to do from the explanation.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no `\g` or concept of a global search, as the .NET `Regex` class is global by default.  In other words, it should just work, assuming you've written your regular expression properly.

You might want to test it in [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) and then once you've got it working click the `.NET` button at the top to get the code with properly escaped strings.

Comment: thank you for this. i got tripped up because i forgot that `^` outside of `[]`'s indicates the beginning of string. so my regex was `^[stuff]` and it replaced the first character and nothing else. what i wanted was `[^stuff]`.